# Trying to run a file but receiving error. Works fine on another computer

Tags: ruby

This is the error when entering URI:

```
/Users/wiggum/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:66:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?): http://www.treasuredata.com (URI::InvalidURIError)
    from /Users/wiggum/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:72:in `parse'
    from /Users/wiggum/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/common.rb:226:in `parse'
    from sitecrawl.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

here is my code which runs fine on my other computer. Any suggestions?

```
require 'Spidr'
require 'csv'
require 'Nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

puts "What is the website you are looking to crawl?"

site = gets
#make a filename
f2 = ".csv"
f1 = URI.parse(site).host
filename = "#{f1}#{f2}"

CSV.open(filename, "wb") do |csv|
    csv <<["Url", "Title Tag", "H1 Tags", "Meta Desc"]
    Spidr.site(site) do |spider|
        spider.every_url do |url|
            page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)) rescue nil
            title = page.xpath('//title') rescue nil
            desc = page.xpath("//meta[@name='description']/@content") rescue nil
            h1 = page.xpath('//h1') rescue nil
            puts "#{url}   #{title}"
            puts "#{h1}     #{desc}"
            csv <<["#{url}", "#{title}", "#{h1}", "#{desc}"]
        end`enter code here`
    end
end
```

Comment: FYI, I have already installed all the necessary gems also.

Answer (score 1):

No idea why it works on your other computer, it shouldn't work anywhere. `gets` grabs the entire string that you enter **including the trailing newline**, so the string you're trying to parse is actually: `http://www.treasuredata.com\n` which is not a valid URI.

Change your `gets` to a `gets.chomp`